# Codeigniter 4 Pagination with join tables showing error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am working on codeigniter project. I am showing news table with join left news category and paginate. When I tried the below code I get an error `Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Builder::paginate()`. How to show news data with join and pagination?

```
    $db      = \Config\Database::connect();
    $news_tbl = $db->table('tbl_news')->join('tbl_category', 'tbl_news.category_id = tbl_category.category_id');
    $data['news_fetched'] = $news_tbl->paginate(10);
    $data['pager'] = $news_fetched->pager;
    $data['links'] = $data['pager']->links();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Result::paginate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184329/error-call-to-undefined-method-codeigniter-database-mysqli-resultpaginate)

Comment: @mickmackusa can you show how to change paginate to object

Comment: Did you have a good read of the CI4 Pagination docs? I don't have a project on CI4, so I cannot be sure, but I don't see any mention of `pagination()`. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html Do you need to load the service whereever it is that you are calling this? (I assume your model, but I have seen questions with querybuilder calls inappropriately coming from controllers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$db->table()` creates a query builder object. Pagination works with model objects. You're not setting your pagination the right way.
You should create a Model file called **tblNewsModel** that will handle pagination for you.

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;

class tblNewsModel extends \CodeIgniter\Model {

    protected $table = 'tbl_news';
    protected $primaryKey = 'your_pk_id';

    // your function to paginate
    public function paginateNews(int $nb_page) {
        return $this->select()->join('tbl_category', 'tbl_news.category_id = tbl_category.category_id')->paginate($nb_page);
    }

}
```

And then in your controller, just create a new instance of this model and ask him to give you the pagination

```php
$tblNewsModel = new \App\Models\tblNewsModel();
$data['news_fetched'] = $tblNewsModel->paginateNews(10);
$data['pager'] = $tblNewsModel->pager;
$data['links'] = $data['pager']->links();
```